# Add attribute to html tag with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, dom-events

I am using a Javascript code to detect if a video is loaded.

Once it is loaded I want to add an `autoplay` attribute to the `<video>` tag to make it play but I can't find a way to add that attribute. Here is the code I use:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var video = document.querySelector('#bgvid');
    var div = document.getElementById('#bgvid');

    function checkLoad() {
        if (video.readyState === 4) {
            alert('video is loaded')
            video.setAttribute("autoplay")
        } else {
            setTimeout(checkLoad, 100);
        }
    }

    checkLoad();
}, false);
```

******************* THE SOLUTION ********************

First, thanks **DontVoteMeDown** for the help.

Proper code should be:

```
document.getElementById('bgvid').addEventListener('canplaythrough', function() {
    this.play();
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not add the attribute to the tag? From the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video#Attributes):

> **autoplay**: (...) the video will automatically begin to play back as soon as it can do so without stopping to finish loading the data.

So I presume (not sure, indeed) that the video will start playing as soon it loads a part of the video.

Anyway, if you still want to add the attribute, the `video` tag has some [Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events), from docs:

- `canplay`: Sent when enough data is available that the media can be played, at least for a couple of frames;
- `canplaythrough`: Sent when the ready state changes to CAN_PLAY_THROUGH, indicating that the entire media can be played without interruption(...);

So you can use one of those events to set the attribute, e.g:

```
document.getElementById('bgvid').addEventListener('canplay', function() {
    this.setAttribute("autoplay", "autoplay");
});
```

With this you can avoid using *timeouts*, which isn't the best approach.

Comment: I know autoplay is supposed to make video start play only when enough data is buffered, but actually each browser behaves differently, and sometimes video is stuck, this is why I prefer to first load the full video and only then to play it

Comment: Your code was good - one thing that needed to change is the setattribute, as it turns, adding autoplay attribute after document is loaded doesn't help. proper solution was to add video.play()

Comment: @EyalBinehaker nice, you ended with the perfect solution.

Answer (score 1):

with autoplay enabled there is no need to check its load state, the video will simply play when it can, is loaded.

```
video.autoplay = true;
```

Look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_prop_autoplay.asp)

Comment: Thanks for the help, as it turns, adding autoplay attribute after document is loaded doesn't help. proper solution is video.play().